# codeigniter sessions creates two different sessions

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, session, redirect

Codeigniter sessions creating two different session for same website name.

**Scenario:**

1. domainname.com
2. www.domainname.com

In both cases it is creating two different sessions. But when I type the same url in IE-10 it's creating only single session, but it is not working in firefox & chrome.

My **ci_config** file is as follows:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE; 
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 1800;
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use redirect domainname.com to www.domainname.com in .htaccess file
this will solve your problem

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```